# Returning to different parent activities

Tags: android, android-activity, parent

I currently could only return to one parent activity, which is my launch page. I am using the back button on the title bar(top left corner). I would like to enable the back button to return to the previous page instead of going straight back to launch page (there was a white screen before going back anyway).

I have tried the codes below, and my launch page is Aucon, the page i want to return to, for some activities, is SignIn page, but i couldn't. Is there anything wrong with my codes or it naturally does not allow? Please advice.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".AucOn">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="Register"
        android:parentActivityName=".AucOn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn"
        android:label="Home"
        android:parentActivityName=".AucOn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BuyerHome"
        android:label="Buyer Home"
        android:parentActivityName=".SignIn" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Instructions"
        android:label="Instructions"
        android:parentActivityName=".AucOn" />

    <activity
        android:name=".CustomerSupport"
        android:label="Customer Support"
        android:parentActivityName=".AucOn" />

    <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword"
        android:label="Forgot Password"
        android:parentActivityName=".AucOn" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Comment: Are you able to return from BuyerHome to SignIn. If you can , then I did not get your question.

Comment: No,I wasn't able to, and yes that's the problem I am experiencing

Comment: For API levels below 16, we need to add meta data <meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value=".MainActivity" /> inside that activity. Check https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.

Comment: Hi, nothing changed though. it still can't perform.

Comment: That is strange. Would you delete android:parentActivityName=".AucOn" from activity "SignIn" and check what happens.

Comment: It still doesn't work man.

Comment: It is very strange. Would you post the onCreate() method of BuyerHome, SignIn and also at least  the part of the code where you are using Intent (I guess) to move from one activity to other activity for AucOn and SignIn.

Comment: Sorry,i can't post anymore questions alr.

Comment: I am just asking to add in this question only if possible. Also you may try what Gourav suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try Using the `OnBackPressed()` override method. It will take you to the previous screen.

```
 YourBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

I hope this might work.

Answer (score 0):

With what I see, I think you want to implement the back button on Android in some activity not to go to the `AucOn` activity. If I'm right, then you can override the `onBackPressed()` method in the activity you want and open the `SignIn` activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SignIn.class);
}
```

This will instruct the activity to look for the real back button press on Android and open the required activity.
Now for the toolbar back button, you have to set a navigation click listener like this:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SignIn.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
});
```

This will add the click listener for the toolbar back button click.

Comment: Hi I dont know how to call my toolbar back button. can you help?

Comment: Set the navigation onClick listener on the toolbar, I have added it in the answer.

Comment: Have you tried it, If it works, please accept my answer as working one.